# Issue forcing a return -1 from function in C

Tags: c, function, debugging, return

Creating a banker's program in beginner's C class.  All of my code works successfully (after testing all cases), except for forcing a return of negative one in part of the loop.  When the value is returned by copy to the main program it alters the balance.

Function return

```
  else { //If the amount to be withdrawn from the account is greater than the existing amount
        printf("Error. Withdrawal must be less than account balance.\n"); //Output error message
        return -1; //Return a negative one to the main program
  }
```

Return by copy in main

case 3: //Cash Withdrawal

```
        printf("You are about to withdraw cash from an account.\n \n");
        withdrawnAmount = withdrawal(balance); //Calling function to withdraw money from existing account
        balance -= withdrawnAmount;
        printf("Your new account balance is $%d\n\n", balance);
        break;
```

Comment: Images are highly discouraged. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to show the actual code with proper formatting.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in that case you should either `return 0;` so that the amount will not be deducted, like this:

```
 else { //If the amount to be withdrawn from the account is greater than the existing amount
        printf("Error. Withdrawal must be less than account balance.\n"); //Output error message
        return 0; //Return zero to the main program
  }
```

Or, if you want to keep using the negative one, you would need to check the value returned before deducting from the account balance, as follows:

```
case 3: //Cash Withdrawal
    printf("You are about to withdraw cash from an account.\n \n");
    withdrawnAmount = withdrawal(balance); //Calling function to withdraw money from existing account
    if(withdrawnAmount > 0)
       balance -= withdrawnAmount;
    else
       printf("-1");
    printf("Your new account balance is $%d\n\n", balance);
    break;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you.  When I saw your first post I started altering the main program to check the values after return.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome. Will update my answer to include that as well.

Comment: Added this because the professor specifically stated on the assignment he wanted a -1 returned to the main program for this one instance.
   else {
    printf("-1\n");
   }
   break;